# Why is the date converted incorrectly on some android devices?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm converting a string to date using SimpleDateFormat. It works fine on all the devices I've tested except one device Tecno w3 running marshmallow android 6.0.

I have failed to figure out why it passes a wrong date for this particular device. I haven't tested on other android 6.0 devices so I'm not sure if the problem persists on other devices running marshmallow. What could be the issue and how can it be resolved?

```java
String dateString = "2019-09-02T08:21:12.157+0000";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);

            try {
                Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The date parsed on the tecno w3 is `2019-08-21T02:09:12.157+0300` yet it should be `2019-09-02T11:21:12.157+0300`

I have tried to use Calendar

```java
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,  8);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 21);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 12);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 157);

        Date date = cal.getTime();
```

The date parsed with this method is still `2019-08-21T02:09:12.157+0300`

I've also tried using Joda Time

```java
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(dateString);
Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

The date parsed is still `2019-08-21T02:09:12.157+0300`

Why is this happening on this device and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the device running on Julian calendar instead of Gregorian?

Comment: Weird. I have not understood how this behaviour can be possible.

Comment: Close, @laalto. If the calendar of the formatter used for parsing has the Gregorian change in the past, and the one used for formatting has got it in the future, I get `2019-08-20T10:21:12.157+0200` in my time zone. 15 hours off from the reported. Seems it can account for the whole days, but not for the hours, though.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. Whether it solves your problem on that particular device I dare not tell.

Comment: What happens with other datetimes? Are they 12 days 15 hours off too? Or some other amount? Please try with a date from a year ago, 100 years ago, in one year, in 100 years.